# PHP Stay logged erro

Tags: php

I'm trying to login and get information from other page, using this functions:

```
function curl($url,$post="",$header=false, $ref=false) {  
    $ch = curl_init();
    if($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.35 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.10 Chromium/13.0.764.0 Chrome/13.0.764.0 Safari/534.35"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); 
    if($ref) { 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); 
    return $result;
}
function array_remove_empty($arr){
    $narr = array();
    while(list($key, $val) = each($arr)){
        if (is_array($val)){
            $val = array_remove_empty($val);
            // does the result array contain anything?
            if (count($val)!=0){
                // yes :-)
                $narr[$key] = trim($val);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (trim($val) != ""){
                $narr[$key] = trim($val);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($arr);
    return $narr;
}
function getStr($string,$start,$end){
    $str = explode($start,$string);
    $str = explode($end,$str[1]);
    return $str[0];
}
function inStr($s,$as){ 
        $s=strtoupper($s); 
        if(!is_array($as)) $as=array($as); 
        for($i=0;$i<count($as);$i++) if(strpos(($s),strtoupper($as[$i]))!==false) return true; 
        return false; 
}
```

To check headers:

```
        $url = "https://account.peixeurbano.com.br/login";
        $var = 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.peixeurbano.com.br%2FConta&email='.$email.'&password='.$pass.'&client_id=6';
        $page = curl($url, $var, $cookie);

  $estado = getStr($page,'"estado":"','",');

    echo ">>".$page.$estado."";
        if(inStr($page, 'ASPXAUTH')){
           //HERE COMES THE PROBLEM
           //LOGGED
        } elseif(inStr($page, 'view=login')) {
            //NOT LOGGED
        }
```

I want to to get body information from asecondary page after login, (login check is working) but when i try to CURL another page... the page redirect to login page again. What can i do to stay logged, to get information for a secondary page?

I'm new on PHP.

Comment: You probably lack some vital information expected by the server. We cannot say what it is, you will have to find out yourself. I suggest you use a network sniffer (`wireshark` or `tcpdump`) and dump two requests to that secondary page. One using a browser (successful), one using `cURL` (failing). Then compare both closely.